# How do I add a mouseclick event to a winform treenode?

Tags: treenode

How do I add a mouseclick event to a winform treenode?

#### Update

Note that I want to do this at runtime.

Comment: I'd like to know what the "quality standard" algorithm finds wrong about my question.

Comment: It's probably just the length of the question...

Comment: So I rack my brain to shorten the question and the algo says no? Silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this dynamically you need to handle the TreeView's NodeMouseClick event thusly:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.NodeMouseClick += 
                new TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(treeView1_NodeMouseClick);

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node 1"));
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node 2"));
        }

        void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicked: " + e.Node.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would that not give me a mouseDoubleClick event on the entire treeview? I want to add them on each treenode within the treeview...

Comment: Are you adding the nodes dynamically?

Comment: ok. It's best to use the NodeMouseClick event. Check out the new snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using that :)